# Can't launch Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I just finished installing ros full desktop package and gazebo but when I run gazebo in terminal it simply doesn't launch. I'm going crazy since I can't find anyone else with this problem. I'm running it on a desktop with dedicated graphics. Does anyone have an idea of how to solve the problem?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using jade and gazebo5, btw

EDIT2: When I run gazebo --verbose it gives me:

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2012-2015 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.1.86
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2012-2015 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.1.86
[Err] [RTShaderSystem.cc:414] Unable to find shader lib. Shader generating will fail.[Err] [Server.cc:285] Could not open file[worlds/empty.world]
```

EDIT3: I noticed I have several gazebos in /usr/share folder. Gazebo3 and Gazebo5.4 and when I run this command:

```
export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/share/gazebo-5.0:/usr/share/gazebo_models:${GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH}
```

I am able to run gazebo but I have to do it every single time I open the terminal. Is there any way to make it permanent?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257616/can%27t-launch-gazebo/) by [sirsomething](https://answers.ros.org/users/28660/sirsomething/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To make that permanent you could add it to the bottom of your .bashrc file in your home folder (`gedit ~/.bashrc`). Everything in that file is ran when you open a new terminal.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sirsomething](https://answers.ros.org/users/28660/sirsomething/) on 2017-03-23**:
This worked well! Thanks ;)